# Book recommendation/reference request on a gentle introduction to cyclotomic polynomials

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, cyclotomic-polynomials, perfect-numbers

Can anyone recommend a book or reference material (written in English) that offers a gentle introduction to [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial)?

The book does not have to be too comprehensive.

I plan to apply the stuff I have learned from this book to undertake a more in-depth study of properties of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers).

I did study number theory in graduate school, but only up to the level of elementary number theory (using Burton).

Comment: This [4 pages paper](http://perso.eleves.ens-rennes.fr/~lgay/Agregation/Polynomes%20cyclotomiques%20irr%C3%A9ductibles.pdf) provides main cyclotomic polynomial properties. In French though.

Comment: Thank you for providing that link, @mathcounterexamples.net!  However, I would opt for one that is in English, as I currently could not read French.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look about the following references regarding the cyclotomic polynomial:

$(1)~~$ [Number Theory in Science and Communication](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-03430-9) by Manfred R. Schroeder [Chapter 22, Page Number 232-246]
This book provides good examples and the topics are treated informally, stressing intuition rather than formal proofs.
$(2)~~$ [Abstract Algebra](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/algebra/Whole_with_TOC.pdf) by Paul Garrett  [Chapter 8, Page Number 105-117]
This book proves many of the iconic basic facts about cyclotomic polynomials and cyclotomic fields.
$(3)~~$ [Cyclotomic Polynomials](https://www.whitman.edu/documents/Academics/Mathematics/2015/Final%20Project%20-%20Porter%2C%20Brett.pdf) by Brett Porter 
$(4)~~$ [The cyclotomic polynomials](https://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/%7Ejameson/cyp.pdf) by G.J.O. Jameson

All the above references contains detail discussion with lot of examples. I think these may be helpful for understanding the subject. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing these references, @nmasanta!  An upvote for now.  =)